# Autodesk Forge Viewer don't automatically align the model to the center of the viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have an IFC file, with the model component located quite far from the origin (Due to using the correct actual coordinates of the project). After uploaded and translated to Forge, the viewer does not display properly at the location where the model is located. While the url thumbnail still shows the model fit to view. I attach 2 image as follow. Please help how to fix this.

Thumbnail when translation finished:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQTLR.png

Viewer result:
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiqS5.png

Answer (score 0):

Forge is usually able to handle BIM models "far away from the origin" quite well. I'd try the following:

- check if this isn't just some strange camera preset; when the model is loaded, try double-clicking somewhere on the empty space; this should transition the camera so that it's covering the bounding box of the entire model
- alternatively, open the Model Browser panel, and select one of the nodes in the tree to move the camera to it
- the Forge Model Derivative service allows you to switch between different loaders when processing an IFC file (go to https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST > "Attributes by Output Type" > "SVF Output", and search for `conversionMethod` in the advanced properties); give it a try and see if you get better results

And finally, if none of the above helps, consider sharing your IFC design with us (confidentially; we will not share the design with anyone outside of Autodesk) via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com` so that we could debug the issue on our end.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try first. If can not, I'lll send the IFC file follow your link